# Rails is looking for the wrong join tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two Models that begin with the same name: `LawField` and `LawCategory` and there is a `habtm`-association between them. I created the join table via `rails g migration CreateLawCategoriesLawFieldsJoinTable law_categories law_fields`. The migration looks like this:

```
class CreateLawCategoriesLawFieldsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :law_categories, :law_fields do |t|
      # t.index [:law_category_id, :law_field_id]
      # t.index [:law_field_id, :law_category_id]
    end
  end
end
```

When I invoke the `law_fields` method on a `LawCategory` object (or vice versa) I get the error message:

> Could not find table 'law_categories_fields'

Why is rails expecting this name? (Note the missing `law_` before the word `fields`) Am I supposed to name the table like that? Why? I assume this is because the models names are both beginning with `law`. But I see no reason why this would be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I supposed to name the table like that?

Yes, it is [documented](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many):

> If your tables share a common prefix, it will only appear once at the
>   beginning. For example, the tables “catalog_categories” and
>   “catalog_products” generate a join table name of
>   “catalog_categories_products”.

> Why?

I don't know. Cause it's shorter? Because it sounds more natural?

Comment: OK nice to know. Wondering why `create_join_table` does not give it the proper name then. Intentionally confusing or bug?

Answer (score 2):

Your Join table should have a name like this

```
law_categories_fields
```

And your Migration file should look like this

```
class CreateLawCategoriesFieldsJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
def change
    create_table :law_categories_fields do |t|
       t.integer :law_category_id
       t.integer :law_field_id
    end
  end
end
```

For example, the tables `catalog_categories` and `catalog_products` generate a join table name of `catalog_categories_products`.

For more details see [has_and_belongs_to_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many).